# Is it possible to setup routes that the internet works only through VPN connection?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, routing

Is it possible to set up routes that the internet works only through VPN connection? If the vpn is disconnected then the internet shouldn't work.
I found the solution here with the firewall, and it works fine for me, but I wonder if it is possible to do with routes...
Like adding static route through my internet IP only to VPN server IP, and adding default gateway for my  VPN IP..
If so, how to do that on the ubuntu desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's surely possible. I would try the following (this is not tested):

1. in Network Manager settings, remove default gateway from your default interface (if you are using DHCP and it's automatically providing the default gateway for you, change the setting to "DHCP (addresses only)")
2. add in your network settings a static route to your VPN server over the gateway that was your default gateway (if you don't know what the address was, you can obtain it by displaying the current routing table: `netstat -r -n` before performing these steps)
3. you may also need to add in similar way static routes to DNS servers, if your VPN client connects to the server using domain name and not IP address
4. it may be also needed to add DNS server addresses manually in the network settings, especially if you use the "DHCP (addresses only)" option.
5. disconnect your default connection  and connect it again.

Once this is done, you should not be able to connect to anything except your VPN server.

Then you may connect your VPN - I assume that once you connect, the VPN client will automatically set up the default gateway for you over the VPN interface (this is how most VPN clients behave).